# VBA - Sending Emails Through Outlook Based on Cell Data

Tags: vba, excel

I've been failing miserably trying to write code for this, so I'd be happy if someone could help me create a macro in excel. I'm looking to send a bunch of users access credentials through outlook based off data I add to excel. Specifically, I have two worksheets:

1) Email Information (all static)

This contains:

- Email Subject in cell C5
- Email Body in Cell C6 (Essentially this says Hello, your user credentials are below)
- Additional Email Body in Cell C7 (This portion would say something along the lines of "please let us know if you have any questions") Both cells C6 and C7 can of course be updated to include any language

2) User Information (number of users can vary)

This contains:

- Column A - First Name
- Column B - Last Name
- Column C - Full Name (Not really needed)
- Column D - Email Address
- Column E - Password

Ideally, the macro would be able to look at the user information and create a new, separate email from outlook for every email address from column D with the following format:

- Email To: email addresses in cell D2 until last email (User Information worksheet)
- Email Subject: Cell C5 in Email information worksheet
- "Hi" Firstname value from column A in User Information worksheet
- Email Body Part 1 from cell C6 in Email Information worksheet
- Username: which is the email address from column D (same as email recipient)
- Password: from column E in User Information worksheet
- Email Body PArt 2 from cell C7 in Email Information worksheet

Hope someone has the time to help me out.

Thanks in advance!!

***EDIT***

Thanks for the help, Barry. Here is my code as I'm trying to reference two different worksheets. Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub GenerateEmail()
Dim sEmailBodyp1 As String
Dim sEmailBodyp2 As String
Dim sEmailSubject As String
Dim sEmailTo As String
Dim sFirstName As String
Dim sPassword As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSheet As Worksheet
Dim UserSheet As Worksheet
Dim UsedRange As Range

Set EmailSheet = Sheets("Email Information")
Set UserSheet = Sheets("User Information")
Set sEmailSubject = EmailSheet.Cells("C5")
Set sEmailBodyp1 = EmailSheet.Cells("C6")
Set sEmailBodyp2 = EmailSheet.Cells("C7")
Set UsedRange = UserSheet.UsedRange

For Each Row In UsedRange.Rows
    sFirstName = Row.Columns(1)
    sEmailTo = Row.Columns(4)
    sPassword = Row.Columns(5)
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = sEmailTo
        .Subject = sEmailSubject
        .Body = "Hi " + sFirstName + "," + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + sEmailBodyp1 + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Username: " + sEmailTo + vbCrLf + "Password: " + sPassword + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + sEmailBodyp2
        .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
Next

Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: please show us what you have done yourself so far?

Comment: This is fairly easy to write, just please include your (failed) code attempt and then we can help you.

Comment: Without your attempted code this question will likely get closed as "too broad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussions this is my edit for this solution.

### Excel Macro

```
Public Sub GenerateEmail()
Dim sEmailBodyp1 As String
Dim sEmailBodyp2 As String
Dim sEmailSubject As String
Dim sEmailTo As String
Dim sFirstName As String
Dim sPassword As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSheet As Worksheet
Dim UserSheet As Worksheet
Dim UsedRange As Range

Set EmailSheet = Sheets("Email Information")
Set UserSheet = Sheets("User Information")

sEmailSubject = EmailSheet.Range("C5").Value
sEmailBodyp1 = EmailSheet.Range("C6").Value
sEmailBodyp2 = EmailSheet.Range("C7").Value

Set UsedRange = UserSheet.UsedRange

For Each Row In UsedRange.Rows.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, UsedRange.Columns.Count)

        sFirstName = Row.Columns(1)
        sEmailTo = Row.Columns(4)
        sPassword = Row.Columns(5)
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = sEmailTo
            .Subject = sEmailSubject
            .Body = "Hi " + sFirstName + "," + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + sEmailBodyp1 + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Username: " + sEmailTo + vbCrLf + "Password: " + sPassword + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + sEmailBodyp2
            .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing

Next

Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Adding updates shortly

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the code example.  I have updated my answer to reflect your additions.  Two things... string types do not use the keyword 'set'.  Also, the value for sEmailSubject is derived from a Range, as opposed to a Cell.

Comment: this is beautiful - thanks so much! I'll take a look and let you know if anything isn't working. Thanks again!!

Comment: if I want to start this from cell 2 and down (since the top row is headers), how would I do that?

Comment: @Tom - (see example in my edited answer) to exclude row modify for each line: For Each Row In UsedRange.Rows.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, UsedRange.Columns.Count)

Comment: @Tom - Glad to help!