# Importing too much information into E-mail

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a list of emails and information I need to loop through. The spreadsheet table column structure is as follows:

```
Email | Irrelevant Information | Relevant Information
```

The issue I am running into is I only want the relevant info cell to be sent in the body of the email (appended to the end of some text). I found some code online that I've been able to modify and it mostly works. Originally the entire spreadsheet was being added to each email but now it is adding the entirety of the row below the .Introduction text.

```
Sub EmailRange()

Dim WorkRng As Range
For i = 2 To Ubound 'starting at 2 to skip column headers
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorkRng.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
                .Introduction = "Text" + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value 'append relevant info to text
                .Item.To = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) 'cycling through each email
                .Item.Subject = "Subject"
                .Item.send
        End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Things I have tried:

1. Removing the range definition. This causes the script to revert back to attaching the entire sheet.
2. Setting the range to the relevant info cell. The entire row is still being added to the message.
3. Changing ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope to ActiveCell.MailEnvelope. Compiles fine but does not send emails.

Comment: Where do you define `n`?  Is `n` supposed to be the last row in the range?

Comment: According to [Ron DeBruin's website](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm) I dont think its possible to just use the value of one cell.  Have you tried do this through Outlook?

Comment: n was just a placeholder for the last row, I updated the code example to make it more clear. I have spent some time on Ron's website but didn't find the answer (maybe I am not asking the right question, though). I have not tried through Outlook, I didn't even consider trying from that angle.

Comment: Yeah if you're working with Outlook, that is the way to go. `MailEnvelope` is pretty limited.

Comment: Try the link in my previous comment and read through that as it goes through using the MailEnvelope in Excel.  If you want to try to use Outlook here is a great link here on SO [Sending Emails through Outlook based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101886/vba-sending-emails-through-outlook-based-on-cell-data)

Comment: @ZackE thanks, I will look at it from that angle.

Comment: No problem.  I also posted what I use for one of my email procedures as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I use when needing to send information through an email.  You would need to refactor it to suit your needs.  It does use a function to format the HTML in the body of the email with some information.  It may be a little overkill for what you need, but should point you in the right direction.

This sub generates and sends the email:

```
Sub AppraisalReviewEmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
    Dim clsDate As Range, CustName As Range, PreSign As Range
    Dim strBody As String, CindyAppraisalEmail As String, hyperlink As String, currDir As String, Target As String, lNum As String

    Set clsDate = GeneralInfo.Range("genCloseDate")
    Set PreSign = SheetData.Range("Pre_Sign_Date")
    Set CustName = LoanData.Range("CustName1")

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    lNum = GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanNumber")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    AppraisalEmail = redacted for public viewing
    currDir = MLAChecklist.path
    hyperlink = "<a href=""" & Replace(currDir, " ", "%20") & """>" & currDir & "</a>"

    Dim Subj As String, EmailAddr As String

    With MItem
        .To = AppraisalEmail
        .Subject = UCase("Appraisal Review" & " - " & CustName & " - " & lNum & " - " & "Closing Date " & clsDate)
        .Display
        .htmlbody = getAppraisalCheckListHTML(hyperlink, getAppraisalCheckListItems) & .htmlbody
        .Send
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

These Functions create the body of the email with an ordered list based on items in a specific cell:

```
Option Explicit
Function getAppraisalCheckListItems() As String

    getAppraisalCheckListItems = "<li>" & Replace(SheetData.Range("Notes_for_Appraisal_Review").value, ",", "</li>" & vbNewLine & "<li>") & "</li>"

End Function
Function getAppraisalCheckListHTML(HyperlinkTag As String, CheckListItems As String) As String
    Const Delimiter As String = vbNewLine
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim empName As String

    empName = "Roger Rabbit"

    If Len(SheetData.Range("Notes_for_Appraisal_Review")) = 0 Then
        With list
            .Add "<html>"
            .Add "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>"
            .Add "Hello " & empName & ","
            .Add "<p>Please complete the appraisal review for the following file:"
            .Add "&nbsp&nbsp"
            .Add HyperlinkTag
            .Add "<br><br>"
            .Add "Thank You,"
            .Add "</p>"
            .Add "</body>"
            .Add "</html>"
        End With
    Else
        With list
            .Add "<html>"
            .Add "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>"
            .Add "Hello " & empName & ","
            .Add "<p>Please complete the appraisal review for the following file:"
            .Add "&nbsp&nbsp"
            .Add HyperlinkTag
            .Add "<br><br>"
            .Add "Items to make note of in the file."
            .Add "<ol>"
            .Add Trim(CheckListItems)
            .Add "</ol>"
            .Add "<br>"
            .Add "Thank You,"
            .Add "</p>"
            .Add "</body>"
            .Add "</html>"
        End With
    End If

    getAppraisalCheckListHTML = Join(list.ToArray, Delimiter)

End Function
```